# C: Only compiles if assigned after declaration

Tags: c

This gives compilation error.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 1, 2, 3;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

But,

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    a = 1, 2, 3;
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

prints 1. Why? I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code, comma is used as a separator. 
In your second code, it's used as operator.

So, the first code is simply gives error.

In the [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), comma operator has the least precedence. So, in the second program,

```
a = 1, 2, 3
```

is equivalent to

```
(a = 1), 2, 3
```

As, a=1, 1 is printed.

[The Wiki article for this one is just fine.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Answer (score 3):

Ah the comma oprator :).

In C, the comma is an operator just like +, - * and /. This means it obeys rules of precendence, and it has a very low precedence (the lowest, in fact). Given that is has a lower precedence than the assignment operator, it is evaluated after any assignments in the same expression. When you type:

```
a = 1, 2, 3;
```

It evaluates the assignment, a = 1, and then the comma(s). This is equivalent to writing:

```
(a = 1), 2, 3;
```

If you were to place brackets in your code, the value assigned to a would differ would differ:

```
a = (1, 2, 3); // a now equals 3.
```

This is because the comma operator discards the left hand argument, and results in the right hand argument. So in this case, 1,2 evaluates to 2, and 2,3 evalues to 3.

The first example fails to compile because C supports the following syntax:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

Which declares 3 variables a, b and c, assigning values 1, 2 and 3, respectively. The combination of the = and , operators is confusing, hence why what you've written causes a compiler error. If you were to rewrite your assignment as follows:

```
int a = (1, 2, 3);
```

It clarifies the order of operations, and assigns the value 3 to a.

[Here's](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html) a table showing operator precedence in C.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line:

```
int a = 1, 2, 3;
```

you are attempting to declare variables 2 and 3 of type `int`, which i'n't allowed.

```
int a = 1, b, c;  // OK
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3; // OK
int a = (1, 2, 3); // OK - a == 3
```

In the second line:

```
a = 1, 2, 3;
```

you're using a comma operator; `a` is assigned 1 (not 3 as I first wrote; comma has the lowest of all operator precedences - and the 2 and 3 are thrown away).

Answer (score 1):

As part of a declaration, a comma means that another declaration (of the same type) follows.

In your second example , it's the comma operator, which has very low precedence. It's equivalent to

```
(a = 1), 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the standard says so:

```
(6.7) declaration:
    declaration-speciﬁers init-declarator-listopt ;
(6.7) declaration-speciﬁers:
    storage-class-speciﬁer declaration-speciﬁersopt
    type-speciﬁer declaration-speciﬁersopt
    type-qualiﬁer declaration-speciﬁersopt
    function-speciﬁer declaration-speciﬁersopt
(6.7) init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator
(6.7) init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
(6.7.8) initializer:
    assignment-expression
(6.5.16) assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
(6.5.17) expression:
    assignment-expression
    expression , assignment-expression
```

In the initializer (6.7) the comma is a separator. In the expression (6.5.17) the comma is an operator.